# Replace specials chars with HTML entities

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, bcp

I have the following in table `TABLE`

```
id    content
-------------------------------------
1     Hellö world, I äm text
2     ènd there äré many more chars
3     that are speçial in my dat£base
```

I now need to export these records into HTML files, using bcp:

```
set @command = 'bcp "select [content] from [TABLE] where [id] = ' + 
            @id queryout +' + @filename + '.html" -S ' + @instance +
            ' -c -U ' + @username + ' -P ' + @password"

exec xp_cmdshell @command, no_ouput
```

To make the output look correct, I need to first replace all special characters with their respective HTML entities (pseudo)

```
insert into [#temp_html] ..
replace(replace([content], 'ö', '&ouml;'), 'ä', '&auml;')
```

But by now, I have 30 nested `replace`s and it's starting to look insane.

After much searching, I found [this post which uses a HTML conversion table](http://www.manfredkipfelsberger.de/how-to-html-encode-special-characters-in-t-sql/) but it is too advanced for me to understand:

1. The table does not list the special chars itself as they are in my text (`ö, à` etc) but UnicodeHex. Do I need to add them to the table to make the conversions that I need?
2. I am having trouble understanding how to update my script to replace all special chars. Can someone please show me a snippet of (pseudo) code?

Comment: You could make a simple table in a way easy to understand for you, with columns like sourcecharacter,destinationcharacter, and run a loop (cursor) to do all you REPLACEs. That would keep your code tidy, and do the job. You could also have 30 update lines, instead of nesting. It's your eye-candy, your rules.

Comment: This answer may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818394/9395740

Comment: @MJH the answer in the link is good for a single string, I don't think you can use the same technique with a table column.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that with a translation table is using a recursive cte to do the replaces, and one more cte to get only the last row of each translated value.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    id int,
    content nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @T (id, content) VALUES
(1,     'Hellö world, I äm text'),
(2,     'ènd there äré many more chars'),
(3,     'that are speçial in my dat£base')
```

Then, create and populate the translation table (I don't know the HTML entities for these chars, so I've just used numbers [plus it's easier to see in the results]). Also, please note that this can be done using yet another cte in the chain.

```
DECLARE @Translations AS TABLE
(
    str nchar(1),
    replacement nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Translations (str, replacement) VALUES
('ö', '-1-'),
('ä', '-2-'),
('è', '-3-'),
('ä', '-4-'),
('é', '-5-'),
('ç', '-6-'),
('£', '-7-')
```

Now, the first cte will do the replaces, and the second cte just adds a row_number so that for each id, the last value of lvl will get 1:

```
;WITH CTETranslations AS
(
    SELECT id, content, 1 As lvl
    FROM @T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, CAST(REPLACE(content, str, replacement) as nvarchar(100)), lvl+1
    FROM CTETranslations
    JOIN @Translations 
        ON content LIKE '%' + str + '%' 
), cteNumberedTranslation AS
(
    SELECT id, content, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY lvl DESC) rn
    FROM CTETranslations
)
```

Select from the second cte where rn = 1, I've joined the original table to show the source and translation side by side:

```
SELECT r.id, s.content, r.content
FROM @T s
JOIN cteNumberedTranslation r
    ON s.Id = r.Id
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Id
```

Results:

```
id  content                             content
1   Hellö world, I äm text              Hell-1- world, I -4-m text
2   ènd there äré many more chars       -3-nd there -4-r-5- many more chars
3   that are speçial in my dat£base     that are spe-6-ial in my dat-7-base
```

Please note that if your content have more that 100 special chars, you will need to add the `maxrecursion 0` hint to the final select:

```
SELECT r.id, s.content, r.content
FROM @T s
JOIN cteNumberedTranslation r
    ON s.Id = r.Id
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Id
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 );
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/HUQ59223)